# $L^1$-blow up in the free Schroedinger evolution

Tags: functional-analysis, dispersive-pde

I would like to understand, possibly with an explicit example, how the free Schroedinger evolution does not leave $L^1$ invariant.

More precisely: given $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R}^d)\cap L^2(\mathbb{R}^d)$, it is standard that $e^{it\Delta}f\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^d)\cap L^\infty(\mathbb{R}^d)\cap C^0(\mathbb{R}^d)$; can one find such a $f$ so that $\|e^{i t \Delta}f\|_1\to+\infty$ as $t\to t_0$ ?

Comment: Do you know $e^{it\Delta}f(x)$ explicitly? If not, first try to find it out. It is well known ...,  This should be helpful.

Comment: Side Note: $e^{it\Delta}: L^{p} \to L^{p}$ bounded iff $p=2.$